# SQL select for each record

Tags: sql, foreach

i'm new to SQL and i'm getting mad trying to write a simple select to generate a table.
I have a table with the relation between different codes and i have to  generate a table that correlate each code that is related from and to the same key, something like that:

```
TABLE CODES

    CODE|KEY
    -------------
    A|B
    C|B
    D|B
    E|F
    G|F

GENERATED TABLE
--------------------
A|B
B|A
C|B
B|C
D|B
B|D
A|C
C|A
A|D
D|A
C|D
D|C
E|F
F|E
G|F
F|G
E|G
G|E
```

Hope i've been able to explain my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the first row of the database table should be reapeated twice in the SELECT query.That means if first row is first1,second1 the selected table should display results like "first1,second1"as first row and second1,first1 as second row??

Comment: This is not a "simple" query, this is a recursive query you're looking for. Normal SQL queries are not recursive. Which SQL database are you using? Some don't even support recursive queries.

Comment: By now i'm using an sql server 2008 r2 with advanced services but in a couple of months i'm moving to an sql server 2014 enterprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self join that prevents the rows from joining to themselves

```
   select c1.code,c2.code
    from codes c1 join codes c2
    on c1.key = c2.key and c1.code != c2.code
```

should return

```
A|C
A|D
C|A
C|D
D|A
D|C
E|G
G|E
```

work, however it would not return the B and F pairings you'd need rows `B|B` and `F|F` in your codes table

Alternatively you could union the results with your base table so:

```
select c1.code as code1,c2.code as code2
from codes c1 join codes c2
on c1.key = c2.key and c1.code != c2.code
union
select code as code1,key as code2 
from codes
union
select key as code1,codes as code2
from codes
```

should return

```
Code1|Code2
    A|C
    C|A
    A|D
    D|A
    C|D
    D|C
    E|G
    G|E
    A|B
    C|B
    D|B
    E|F
    G|F
    B|A
    B|C
    B|D
    F|E
    F|G
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the easiest way to achieve my goal, even if it tickles me to understand how recursive queries work.

Comment: Sql is built around handling data in sets. Its usually best to script in a set based manner. Recursion is possible through cursors. But best practice is to use them only when necessary. If you really want a recursive solution I will have a go when I get to my pc. But you may find the original solution is more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question?

To create a new table from a select statement you can use

```
SELECT *
INTO CORRELATED
FROM CODES
```

Is this what you mean ?